# Is type conversion possible with inheritance in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, oop

I'm using Ruby, and writing classes with inheritance.

For example:

```
class Canine
  def initialize
  end

  def make_noise
    puts "whoosh whoosh"
  end
end

class Dog < Canine
  def initialize
  end

  def make_noise
    puts "wong wong"
    super
  end
end
```

Now I have a dog object:

```
jack = Dog.new
```

Is it possible to call the `make_noise()` method of Canine through the `dog` object?

In other languages it would be a typecast, something like:

```
(Canine)jack.make_noise
```

Note this is not Ruby syntax, hence, my question.

Is it possible to do this in Ruby?  And if so, how?

Comment: Do you want to call *only* Canine's `make_noise` method, or have `Dog.make_noise` call it? If it's the later, then that will work as is.

Comment: `initialize`, not `initalize`.

Comment: @why you want to do that?

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
Canine.instance_method(:make_noise).bind(jack).call
```

A better plan would be to just give the method in the super class an alias, or rename it.

Comment: +1 A better plan would be to just give the method in the super class an alias, or rename it.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby does not allow casting or conversion in this fashion, at least not in the conventional sense. This is rarely necessary anyway, since Ruby is based on [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) and not a rigid type system.

Are you expecting "whoosh whoosh" from the call? That's something that would only happen with non-virtual methods in a more strictly typed language like C++. It goes against proper object oriented design.

If you explore the [design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) employed in object-oriented design, you can always solve this sort of problem another way.

What you might want here is a presenter to handle the `make_noise` functionality.

Otherwise you'll need to write a `to_canine` method that can convert to the base type, though it's still not clear why you'd need such a thing.

Comment: Thank you. I'll consider other solutions as well.  How would you write the to_canine() method?  As it would solve my problem:  jack.to_canine.make_noise

Comment: I'd really recommend you don't go that way. The usual `to_` methods in Ruby are like `to_i`, converting to integer, or `to_s` to convert to string. They are light-weight and trivial to implement. You'd probably need to allow `initialize` to take in an arbitrary object and convert it to Canine, so `to_canine` is `Canine.new(self)` roughly. What you're doing goes against the grain of Smalltalk design principles and will only create trouble. It even goes against proper C++ design practices as well. In short it seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
d = Dog.new
d.class.superclass.instance_method(:make_noise).bind(d).call
```

or

```
Canine.instance_method(:make_noise).bind(d).call
```

. . . not pretty! I'm not sure if there's a better way

Edit: I think I agree with other answers here, in that Ruby's approach to OO will give you access to other patterns that achieve whatever goals this construct might help you with (perhaps in other languages). I don't see this kind of class/superclass method munging in practice on projects I have been involved in.

Comment: Thank you.  The syntax is a bit long-windeded, and not object-oriented.  Is it at all possible to get the parent object?  In other words, make this object behave like an object of its parent class?

Comment: @Zack Xu: Not as far as I know in Ruby core, although you could put together something based on method introspection that does something similar with reasonable syntax. Problem is it would be possible to create Ruby classes and objects that such a helper function couldn't properly support.

Comment: Zack Xu: There is no parent object for you to get, really.  You would have to create it yourself.  There is one object with class Dog that has a particular set of instance variables and methods.  If you need to get the parent object for some reason, then maybe it should be a separate object and the Dog could just hold a reference to it (i.e. stop using subclassing and use a different type of relationship).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you need this, depending on needs it may be done totally differently, but with limited knowledge I would suggest this

```
class Dog < Canine
  def initialize
  end

  def make_noise only_parent=false
    puts "wong wong" if !only_parent
    super
  end
end
```

or

```
class Dog < Canine
  def initialize
  end

  alias :make_super_noise :make_noise

  def make_noise
    puts "whoosh whoosh"
    super
  end
end
```